# WebSpeech API keeps returning the same message in the Console per each sentence

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, console.log, webspeech-api

I am trying to make a project where saying a note name will play the specified tone using WebSpeech API. When I say "C", the console should return "C" and play a file ("C.wav"), but when I say anything to the microphone, it only returns a blank string.

[This is what the console returns. I have been saying different sentences to the API, but it will only return ''.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WBSg.png)

This is my code:

**html**:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Other functions</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>
        i cant think, o f anythitng  to don lfor theiosj projehcyt h;kjsbfyuae ro
        <img src="img/robot.png" id="title-img">
        <br>
        <a href="index.html" class="back-btn"> Back </a>
      </h1>
      
    </div>
    <button class="start-btn">
      <img src="img/mic-start.png">
    </button>
    <button class="listen-btn">
      <img src="img/mic-listening.gif">
    </button>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="widget" id="dictaphone">
        <h3 class="sub-title">Dictaphone</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="widget" id="color">
        <h3 class="sub-title">Change color</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="widget" id="other">
        <h3 class="sub-title">Tell it your name</h3>
        <p id="spoken" class="show-text"></p>
        <p id="speaking" class="show-text"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/C.wav" id="C"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/C#.wav" id="Csharp"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/D.wav" id="D"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/D#.wav" id="Dsharp"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/E.wav" id="E"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/F.wav" id="F"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/F#.wav" id="Fsharp"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/G.wav" id="G"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/G#.wav" id="Gsharp"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/A.wav" id="A"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/A#.wav" id="Asharp"></audio>
    <audio style="display: hidden" src="audio/B.wav" id="B"></audio>
      
 
    <script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**javascript** + **jquery**:

```
$(".listen-btn").hide();
      $('#color').hide();
      $('#dictaphone').hide();
      var add_css = {
          'animation-name': 'enlarge',
          'animation-duration': '2s',
          'animation-fill-mode': 'forwards'
        }
        $("#other").css(add_css);
      $(".start-btn").click(function () {
          $(".start-btn").hide();
          $(".listen-btn").show();
          recognition.start();
        });

        $(".listen-btn").click(function () {
          $(".start-btn").show();
          $(".listen-btn").hide();
          recognition.abort();
        });
      var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition
      var SpeechRecognitionEvent = SpeechRecognitionEvent || webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent

      var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
      recognition.continuous = false;
        recognition.lang = 'en-US';
        recognition.interimResults = false;
        recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

        recognition.onresult = function (event) {
          var result = event.results[0][0].transcript;
          var interim_transcript = '';
          var final_transcript = '';
          var text = '';
          for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
              var text = event.results[i][0].transcript;
              final_transcript += text;
              $("#spoken").append(interim_transcript);
            } else {
              var text = event.results[i][0].transcript;
              interim_transcript += text;
              $("#speaking").html(interim_transcript);
            }

          }


        }
      
      function playMusic(){
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        var audioElementSrc = $(this).attr('data-audio-src');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioElementSrc);
        $.get();
        audioElement.addEventListener("loadeddata", function(){
            audioElement.play();
        }, true);
      } 
      
      recognition.onend = function (event) {
          var spoken = $("#speaking").html();
          var add = spoken + "<br>";
          $("#speaking").html("");
          if (spoken == "stop") {
            $(".start-btn").show();
            $(".listen-btn").hide();
            recognition.stop();
          } else if (spoken.toLowerCase("see") || spoken.toLowerCase("c") || spoken.toLowerCase("sea")){
            document.getElementById("#C").play();
          } else {
            $("#spoken").append(add);
            recognition.start();
          }
        console.log(spoken);
      }
```

please explain in simple terms as I am new to coding, thanks

also if this question isn't very clear (I am bad at asking formal questions (online)), do not hesitate to ask me to clarify. I will do so as soon as possible.